# Uncaught DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is my first post on stack but I've been having a lot of trouble with this one piece of code in my discord.js bot program.

I've received the error:

**Uncaught DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at DiscordAPIError (undefined:9:5)
at execute (undefined:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (undefined:96:5)**

I've been trying to use a try catch statement but nothing I've tried seems to work.

Edit2: I only receive the error when I enter an incorrect input.

My code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ValorantAPI = require("unofficial-valorant-api")


async function fetchMatches(region, name, tag, size, mode, map) {
    const matches = await ValorantAPI.getMatches(region, name, tag, size, mode, map)
    //Do something with the data, for an example send it as a Discord Embed into your Discord
}


const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

const prefix = '*';

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args[0].slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase();

    if (cmd === 'rank') {
        const parsedArgs = args
        parsedArgs.shift()
        const userName = parsedArgs.join(' ').split('#')[0]
        const userTag = parsedArgs.join(' ').split('#')[1]

            async function fetchMMR(version, region, name, tag) {
                try{
                    const mmr = await ValorantAPI.getMMR(version, region, name, tag);

                    msg.reply(mmr.data.currenttierpatched); // Replies to discord user with the accounts competitive rank.
                } catch(err) {
                    msg.reply(`There was an error finding that player.`, err);
                }
            }
                fetchMMR("v1", "na", userName, userTag) 
    }
});

client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN);
```

Edit: I should probably mention im using the [unofficialvalorantapi](https://github.com/Henrik-3/unofficial-valorant-api) by Henrik-3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should do some basic debugging. What is the value of `mmr.data.currenttierpatched`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros the value mmr.data.currenttierpatched is the rank of the player in competative matches in a string form. For example with the correct input of 'bailey#333', 'Iron III' should be replied in discord.

Comment: I mean you should log the actual value of `mmr.data.currenttierpatched` to the console. Just add a `console.log(mmr.data.currenttierpatched)` before the `msg.reply` so we can see what it is, not what it is supposed to be.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I used `console.log(mmr.data.currenttierpatched)` with the input of bailey#333 and it gave an output of 'Iron 3'. I have found out that the api doesn't actually throw an error so how would I check if the http response isn't 200?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I actually contacted the developer of the api.
The api didn't actually throw an error because the developer hadn't implemented it yet and he recommended I used an if statement to check if mmr.status == 200 which ended up working for me.